# Allow to include a script but prevent file system access to it

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-include, open-basedir

related to the search I seem to have a rather unpopular problem. I have a server running Plesk and multiple customers set up with a separate web space for each (no ssh access). Further there is a "main" script repository which I put outside the apache folders to have only a single instance to maintain and also prevent direct access via http (instead I am using open_basedir to allow the customers to include the scripts). So far, so good.

Now what I also want to achieve is that noone should be able to view the contents of the included files (e.g. via file_get_contents). More clearly I want **include/require: yes**, access at **file-system level: no**. Is that possible with the above setup? Or is my approach totally wrong in order to achieve this? Or is there even a solution?

Best regards

Andy

Comment: Still relevant - does nobody have a suggestion? :(